Why does earlier gdb gets OSError: [Errno 22] or the latest crash when starting a dap session?
I was trying to debug on nvim using the dap functionality of gdb 14.2 (installed via msys2), but a message Debug adapter didn't respond. Either the adapter is slow (then wait and ignore this) or there is a problem with your adapter or 'gdb' configuration. Check the logs for errors (:help dap.set_log_level) appears, nviem-dap-ui also does not display as expected. I opened the DAP REPL manually and the messages were output normally. The last paragraph in it was:
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Exception in thread DAP:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Public\msys64\ucrt64\lib\python3.11\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Public\msys64\ucrt64\lib\python3.11\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Public/msys64/ucrt64/share/gdb/python\gdb\dap\startup.py", line 51, in really_start_dap
    target()
  File "D:\Public/msys64/ucrt64/share/gdb/python\gdb\dap\startup.py", line 73, in ensure_dap_thread
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Public/msys64/ucrt64/share/gdb/python\gdb\dap\server.py", line 117, in main_loop
    cmd = read_json(self.in_stream)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Public/msys64/ucrt64/share/gdb/python\gdb\dap\io.py", line 27, in read_json
    line = stream.readline()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

When I type .c or use :DapContinue, I get "Session still initializing" and then seven options to choose from. I've uploaded dap.log(using gdb 14.2) here. If I don't explicitly terminate gdb, it will still occupy dap.log after nvim closes.
I first searched on Google, but there was no match or anything useful. I guess Msys2 tools are not suitable for use in a normal Windows environment, but the situation in PowerShell and the MSYS2 UCRT64 terminal are exactly the same (also for 15.1 below). This is unlikely to be a problem with my nvim plugin (the DAP configuration was copied from here, adding the initialize_timeout_sec option) configurations, as lldb is generally working fine (but there are minor issues). I have also tried to install gdb in other ways, such as via w64devkit or Scoop, but the "-i dap" option is not supported by these installations at all. This has a very similar question, but is different in nature.
When I upgraded gdb to 15.1, there were no more error messages, but there are still problems. Here are dap-15.1.log and gdb-15.1.log, corresponding to the following events:

I opened my program and set a breakpoint at line 5 -- which, by the way, needs to read user input -- and started debugging.
Nviem-dap-ui is not started, it is configured to automatically open when DAP starts, but not close when DAP ends (it works fine for lldb). So I opened the REPL manually, and the last paragraph is as follow:

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".


I typed .h, .c, :DapContinue and :DapTerminate, and the last three responses all matched "No active session". Finally I quit nvim with :qa.
I also looked at the task manager and gdb did start for a second or two. Then it shut down.

I kept the error message for gdb 14.2 because everyone else seemed to be using it properly before 15.1 was released, I would be equally grateful if anyone knew the solution for 14.2 but not for 15.1.

Isn't gdb-15.1 available from MSYS2 yet? Because I think there were some DAP fixes in the new release.

@ssbssa I upgraded gdb, but there are still problems. Questions I've updated.

Did you have some breakpoints set before you start debugging? Otherwise your program might have just exited normally.

@ssbssa Yes, I did.

Since I don't see any setBreakpoints request in your logs, I don't think your breakpoints are working.

Er, sorry, the previous dap-15.1.log was not the one with the breakpoint (but it is now). However, it doesn't matter a lot, because my program needs to read user input. @ssbssa
